# Why is namespace overloading not working?

Tags: typescript, namespaces, export, overloading

The next example is trying to overload the namespace `N` but unfortunately the compiler complains that neither `A` nor `B` are exported members of it.

```js
namespace N
{
    export const A = 'hello';
    export const B = 'world';
}

type N = N.A | N.B;

const a: N = N.A;
const b: N = N.B;

console.log(a, b);
```

Nonetheless running the compiled code gives the expected output of the following:

```
hello world
```

So the question obviously is: why is the compiler complaining?  Is it reasonable for it to complain?

> **Note<sub>1</sub>:** The compiler version I'm using is `3.1.1`

> **Note<sub>2</sub>:** I know that the above can be written as an `enum` however keep that in mind that this is an oversimplified example of what I'm trying to achieve and as such this is just the bare minimum which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: You could use `type N = (typeof N)[keyof typeof N]` to capture the namespace's exported values as a union type.

Comment: @Aaron that's a very good point, but as I put it down the comments below Titian Cernicova-Dragomir's answer this expression may work but it does not explain why one has to use `typeof` in the first place!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the constants are values, not types. To get the type of a constant you need to use `typeof`

```
namespace N
{
    export const A = 'hello';
    export const B = 'world';
}

type N = typeof N.A | typeof N.B;

const a: N = N.A;
const b: N = N.B;

console.log(a, b);
```

**Note**: The type and the namespace don't really share anything in common, they are different symbols that just happen to share the same name. There is no merging behavior (such as there would be with interfaces and classes for example)

**Edit**

Q:Why is the type of `N.A` not `string` ?

A:The type of N.A is not string because you used a `const` declaration. If you use a const the narrowest possible type is inferred. In this case that is the string literal type "hello".

Q: Why does `type N = "hello" | "world"` work but not `type N = N.A | N.B;` ?

A:Typescript allows the usage of string literals as types as we saw above. But they are types. You can't use them in an expression, you can only use `N` in a type annotation (ie this does nor work `let a = N`). A variable on the other hand is a value. You can use it in an expression, and not in a type annotation (for example `let o:N.A` is an error). To get to the variable's type you need the `typeof` (so this will work: `let o: typeof N.A`)

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer, however 1. I already said in Note2 that I'm aware of the `enum` solution, 2. your explanation of why it is not working does not make sense when you think about the `type N = "hello" | "world";` as a valid type declaration because those strings are _values_ and not _types_.  Ofc `const h = "hello"; const w = "world"; type N = h | w;` doesn't work which makes me think that the type declaration will only accept literals as values which is weird to say the least.  Moreover naively one would think the type of `N.A` should be a `string`, how come it is not?

Comment: The type of `N.A` is not string because you used a const. If you use a const the narrowest possible type is inferred. In this case that is the string literal type `"hello" `. Which brings me to why you can write `type N = "hello";` Typescript allows the usage of string literals as types. But they are types. You can't use them in an expression, you can only use `N` in a type annotation. A variable on the other hand is a value. You can use it in an expression, and not in a type annotation (try it). To get to the variable's type you need the `typeof` operator as I used in the answer.

Comment: I'll accept your answer, but could you extend it with this explanation as my question was always about the compiler and its complain and was never really about how to solve the toy example I gave.  Cheers mate!

Comment: @PeterVaro Added the explanation, I'd already gone to bed last night :)